# Building a multiplayer game in flash

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to develop a game like wordfeud for android and iPhone. For now I don't have a mac so I am not able to use xcode to develop for iPhone. Therefore I have decided to use adobe AIR so I can link the game to both android and iPhone. Feel free to suggest other solutions if you think my idea is bad.

Well to the problem.. I am able to build offline games like tetris etc. but what should I look into when I want the game to be multiplayer just like wordfeud where you can have several games running at the same time. I know I need a server for this, but can I use xampp for now just to test the application and then export the db to a real server or is it a different kind of server I must use? I am completely lost here so any help would be great.

Comment: your question is overly broad and will result in discussion, try revising your question to something more specific of it might get closed for **not being a real question**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some excellent commercial products aimed ad multiplayer flash games. The top two would be

SmartFox Server http://www.smartfoxserver.com/

and

Electrotank server http://www.electrotank.com/

As an useful aside, there is an accompanying book for flash multiplayer games by one of the founders of Electro tank. Its a very good read and will help you a lot.
[http://www.amazon.com/ActionScript-Multiplayer-Games-Virtual-Worlds/dp/0321643364](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321643364)

You will notice these servers are aimed towards massifly multiplayer online games, but I assure you they are equally suitable for developing a simple game also. They both scale up nicely, and both are free to develop.

I've used Electrotank, and liked it. I have not used Smartfox, but it is widely used in the flash online game world.

Comment: These solutions are good for realtime games but word feud allows game play at users own pace no? So the requirement is more for asynchronous turn based game solution on flash.

Comment: @dhruv chopra - Wordfeud also seems to use in-game chat. But I agree there are other solutions for asynchronous games. Heck - you could even use emails, right? Or BBS? That's how they used to do it back in the day! (before my day...)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken you can use any server which can be accessed with HTTP or Socket connection. AIR for mobile doesn't support ServerSocket and DatagramSocket (UDP) so you can't BE a server.

As for available solutions Google knows lots of them.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this without a central server by utilizing [RTMFP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Media_Flow_Protocol) to facilitate Peer-to-Peer connections instead.

Have a look at [Adobe Cirrus](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/) - there are a number of demo's out there showing RTMFP being used on Android/Air apps.

Comment: Also multicast without a server on a local area network: http://www.flashrealtime.com/local-flash-peer-to-peer-communication-over-lan-without-cirrus/